# I cant see my Toast messages in new Thread(new Runnable()

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, tcp, toast

I have a little problem with displaying messages after connection and disconection.

I am trying when press my connection button and establish communication in new Thread to get toast message: You are connected and also if I am not connected to get the toast in the exception:You are not connected.

I tried to replace new Thread with

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() /*but then It underline*/}).start();` at the end of my code as a mistake.When I delete start and run the app it cant connect to my server.

I tried many solutions but none of them works.I will be very appreciative If you can help me.

```
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
            server = serverTxt.getText().toString();
                Socket socket = new Socket(server, port);
                socket.setSoTimeout(30000);
                connected = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //send the message to the server
                here = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
     }).start();
    }
   });
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside a Fragment?

Comment: 1) you dont need a .start() after runOnUiThread call. 2) trying to use the socket code inside runOnUiThread will probably throw NetworkOnMainThread exception -> use only the toast part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use runOnUiThread as follows:

**DO NOT TRY TO USE SOCKET PART IN UI THREAD, IT WILL THROW AN EXCEPTION**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
  try {
    server = serverTxt.getText().toString();
        Socket socket = new Socket(server, port);
        socket.setSoTimeout(30000);
        connected = true;

     //if inside a fragment, call with getActivity().runOnUiThread()
     Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
     });
    //send the message to the server
        here = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

    } catch (Exception e) {

     //if inside a fragment, call with getActivity().runOnUiThread()
     Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
     });

    }
}

}).start();
```

runOnUiThread is a method. .start() works only on Thread objects and is used to start a new thread. here you want your ui(already running) thread to take focus :)

Comment: I tried the code but when I am not connected doest appear the toast

Comment: Where can I use the socket part?

Comment: check out the full answer. This will work for you :)

Comment: You are not connected will only display if your socket throws an Exception. Else it will not show

Answer (score 3):

You have to show Toasts on the UI thread. You can use a Handler to do this.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: don't use the application context for ui

Comment: postRunnable is underlined

Comment: It should just be post(), sorry.

Comment: I tried it but its not working.My code is in fragment and I have also NFC communication.I dont know is make any difference

Answer (score 0):

You should use it inside the method `runOnUiThread`.

For example:

```
activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using AsyncTask. Within onPostExecute you have access to UI and could make a Toast notification

```
private class operation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                server = serverTxt.getText().toString();
                Socket socket = new Socket(server, port);

                socket.setSoTimeout(30000);
                connected = true;

                return "You are connected";
                //send the message to the server
                here = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You are not connected"

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```